# XML tag removal with similar names

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xml-parsing

```
 XML :
<tag1>

<tag2>

<tag2>
</tag2>

<tag2>
</tag2>

<tag2>
</tag2>

</tag2>

</tag1>
```

I have xml of above type. there is parent node of tag2, inside tag2 there are multiple tag2 child node. I want to remove parent tag2 node from the xml. how can i do it?

i want like below now

```
  <tag1>

  <tag2>---remove

  <tag2>
  </tag2>

  <tag2>
  </tag2>

  <tag2>
  </tag2>

  </tag2>--remove

  </tag1>
```

Comment: Please read [**How do I ask a good question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  After 8 months here asking  9 questions (and never [**accepting**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) an answer), you really should know how to use this site by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible XSL :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tag2[tag2]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**brief explanation :**

- `<xsl:template match="@* | node()">...` : Identity template. This template copies all nodes and attributes where it is applied to to the output XML.
- `<xsl:template match="tag2[tag2]">...` : This template overrides identity template for `<tag2>` element having child another `<tag2>`. This template applies identity template only to the child nodes of the parent `<tag2>` so that the parent `<tag2>` won't be copied to the output XML.